# how to stop loading animation after 3-5 second?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm typed the code follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAwaHd1sfOQ&list=LLjkQ5Jo1v2DmL3nR8c2ZvTA&index=2&t=0s

I want to stop Loading animation after 3-5 second so appear homepage
What should I do?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. The link may eventually become unusable.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a .box which is your 'loader' and #site-container that is the place where is your site content.

So what I did there is hide site content at the begining of visiting site 
and then run timer and when it reach 0 it will remove loader and make content site visible so we have an ilusion of loading into a site

This is the javascript

```
 // Time to remove loading object
    var min = 3; 
    var max = 5;
    // Time after site content will be visible
    var time = generateRandomInteger(min, max);


// Loader object with class '.box'
var loader = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

// Site container 
var siteContainer = document.getElementById('site-container');
    // Hide site container
    siteContainer.style.display = 'none';


// Set interval every 1000ms (one second)
setInterval(countDown, 1000);

/**
* Count down time
*/
function countDown(){
    time--;
    // Check if object should be removed
    if(time <= 0){
        // Remove first object that was found having class .box
        loader[0].remove();
        // Show site content
        siteContainer.style.display = 'block';
        // Clear interval
        clearInterval(countDown);
    }
}

/**
* Returns random integer from min to max range
*/
function generateRandomInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

And this is an example of my body content

```
<body>
    <div class='box'>

        Content...

    </div>

    <div id='site-container'>
        Site content...
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Even though this may answer the question, there is no explanation of your code. Please update your answer to provide an explanation of what you are doing. Thanks!

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina i'm newbie in here. i'm doing project "News" website in Web Programming Subject so i want to loading screen before to Content site. So I asked people in this group. sorry for bad grammar.

Comment: @DcBD OHH thank a lot. I did it already !! but so the content site shows its background picture not full-screen :( , In spite of not having the loader, the content site still full-screen background picture.

Comment: @balthierr could you precise that ? maybe you have to do something with css styles or something